# How to display result of statements without using console.log() in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Say we have a javascript file called "test.js". The code in this file is:

```
// Code 1
let x = 1, y = 2;
x + y;
x * 2;
```

We can run it using `Node test.js` in console (e.g. CMD in Windows). But in this case, nothing will be displayed. We have to modify the code to:

```
// Code 2
let x = 1, y = 2;
console.log(x + y);
console.log(x * 2);
```

to let the following result to be displayed in console:

```
3
2
```

The question is, if there is a method that can make Node.js to display result of statements in console **without** using the **console.log()** method? In other words, if there is a method that can make Node.js to display result of statements in "Code 1" in console directly? (The "display-statement-result-directly" behavior like what PowerShell does)

Comment: You can use [this](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_stdout)

Answer (score 0):

You can use node.js' REPL session. In order to use it, you can open up a terminal and write "node" to enter a REPL (Read, Eval, Print, Loop) session immediately. One of its many benefits is that you can see expression results without logging them directly to the console. You can refer to the [Documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/repl.html#default-evaluation) for more information.

Comment: Thank you. But in REPL session, how to run a script file like the "Code 1" successfully and correctly? What I want to do is running a script file containing multiple statements like the "Code 1", not running statement one by one manually.  I tried the >.load test.js command in REPL, but the result is not correct, and if I load the script file multiple times, an error will occur: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'x' has already been declared".